# DynamoDB SDK async function returns undefined when using sinon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to use sinon to test a piece of code that is using an DynamoDB SDK method **batchGet**. Below the code:

```
const fetchSingleUser = async (userId) => {
    try {
        let queryParams = {RequestItems: {}};
        queryParams.RequestItems['users'] = {
            Keys: [{'UserId': userId}],
            ProjectionExpression: 'UserId,Age,#UserName',
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {'#UserName': 'Name'}
        };
        const res = await docClient.batchGet(queryParams).promise();
        return res.Responses.users[0];
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('users::fetch::error - ', e);
    }
};
```

Below the test using sinon:

```
'use strict';

const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();
let assert = require('assert');

describe('DynamoDB Mock Test', function () {
    let AWS;
    let scriptToTest;
    let batchGetFunc;

    before(function () {
        batchGetFunc = sinon.stub();

        AWS = {
            DynamoDB: {
                DocumentClient: sinon.stub().returns({
                    batchGet: batchGetFunc
                })
            }
        };

        scriptToTest = proxyquire('../index', {
            'aws-sdk': AWS
        });
    });

    it('Should scan using async/await and promise', async function () {
        let result = { UserId: 'segf876seg876', Age: 33, Name: 'Paul' }
        
        batchGetFunc.withArgs(sinon.match.any).returns({
            promise: () => result
        });

        const data = await scriptToTest.fetchSingleUser('segf876seg876');
        console.log('--data: ', data)
        assert.equal(data.UserId, 'segf876seg876');
    });

});
```

**The Problem:**

const data = await scriptToTest.fetchSingleUser('segf876seg876') always returns 'undefined'

Comment: Do you get any error message from `  console.log('users::fetch::error - ', e);`?

Comment: It says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined", since const res did't get any data from await.

Answer (score 1):

Function *fetchSingleUser* always returns 'undefined' because you do not return anything after catch (after error happens). You only define return value on success.

But why errors happens, because *const* **res**  does not contain `Responses.users[0]`.

**Simple solution**:

change `let result = { UserId: 'segf876seg876', Age: 33, Name: 'Paul' }` to satisfy code `Responses.users[0]` to

```js
const result = {
    Responses: {
        users: [{ UserId: 'segf876seg876', Age: 33, Name: 'Paul' }],
      },
    };
```

**Note**: use *const* if you not change variable value.